# Can not call CoreData Entity in Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8-share-extension

I have one Entity called `Item`.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Item)
public class Item: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {

...
}
```

I want to call `Item` in Share Extension like:

```
import UIKit
import Social
import CoreServices
import CoreData

class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {
    
    var item: Item?  // <-- Use of undeclared type 'Item'
}
```

I have set the main App and Share Extension the same App Groups and the same container. Why the [code](https://github.com/tatsuyamoriguchi/Poliver2/blob/c58a7a11e285b87a4f737e2107bcd86e4ba9089a/Poli-Extension/ShareViewController.swift) can call the Entity?

But mine says `Use of undeclared type 'Item'`. How to call CoreData in Share Extension?

### Updated

I follow the comment by @vadian and the `Item` can be used in Share Extension. Thanks @vadian for reminding me!

After modifying the target membership and when I run the Share Extension like:

```
override func didSelectPost() {
    print(Item.some method~)
}
```

Error says `ShareExtension*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: <null> is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'`

But the method `print(Item.some method~)` can be used correctly in main App.

What is the reason of the error occurs? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the target membership set properly?

Comment: @vadian Thanks very much. I will modify the target membership.

Comment: @vadian I modified the target membership, but there is still error when running the code. Could you see the updated question again? If you have some idea, could you answer the question?

Comment: Please **read** the error message. The reason is an invalid fetch request.